# OAuthException with linkedin api & php

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I use linkedin api to retrieve information about people i have their ids.
for one request its done successfully but if their is a loop or even 2 request, the error is in my code :

```
function searchID($id,$oauth)
{
    $url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=$id";
    $oauth->fetch($url, array("format" => "json" ),OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_GET);
    echo $oauth->getLastResponse();
}
foreach ($IDs as $value)
{
  echo $value . "<br />";
  searchID($value,$oauth);
  echo "<br />";
}
```

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OAuthException' with message 'Invalid auth/bad request (got a 404, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)' in oauth->fetch line.

and:
OAuthException: Invalid auth/bad request (got a 404, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect) in the same line .

what should i do please ?